# Contact form going to different url and not sending

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cms, forms, contact-us

I'm trying to add attachment for magento's contact form to allow users to send artwork for their orders and having the follow problem.

The form is on the following url http://boxchilli.co/a3mdirect/final-upload

Once you fill in the information, upload your image and hit submit the form redirects to http://boxchilli.co/contacts/index/post it also doesn't send any email out.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/440759/ I followed this guide on adding upload to the form so my code looks like the following link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the url where you submit the form.
The form action is relative `/contacts/index/post`. It needs to be absolute. `BASE_URL/contacts/index/post`.
For this, edit the template that is rendering the form and add the form action like this:

```
Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post')
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, my form does the following `<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` So I guess I just need to find where getFormAction is called?

Comment: Better look for `setFormAction()` or `form_action="..."`

Comment: I can't seem to find the two above, most likely explains the issue then.

Comment: Found it, was within another file